# Adding an action more than once to a Windows Installer sequence table

Tags: windows-installer

I am pretty sure that this question doesn't exist, but if it does, I apologise in advance and please let me know.

My company has asked me to look into a new installer framework, and I am currently looking at Windows Installer 4.5 (MSI). It does everything we need it to do, so I am looking at limitations, and one thing I cannot find is whether you can write an action, standard or custom, into a sequence table more than once. From what I have seen, people **don't** but it doesn't say anywhere that you **can't**.

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

**Edit** - It is especially important for custom actions, because we write a lot of installer packages with our own code, and it might be necessary to use one custom action on multiple DLLs that we have written. Additionally, we would like a framework that doesn't force us to carry out installation steps in a particular order (it would be arbitrary - in a perfect world), and if we can use one action more than once in a sequence table, it might also be possible to do that.

Comment: Why do you need to this?

Comment: See above, Jason... or anyone else who may ask the same question :)

Comment: See Robs answer.  The custom tables express what to do and the custom action expresses how to do it.  In this way it's loosely couple and highly reusable.  That's kind of the entire point of using Windows Installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per MSDN: [InstallExecuteSequence Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The InstallExecuteSequence table has the following columns.
>
> ColumnType Key Nullable
>
> Action Identifier  Y N
>
> Condition Condition  N Y
>
> Sequence Integer  N Y

The primary key is on Action therefore it can only be listed once.

There may be ways of using MsiDoAction to schedule the custom action dynamically in more then one place but I've never tried.  The real question would be  why do you think you need to do this?  In 10 years of writing MSI's, I've never needed to.

Comment: It is more about testing the limits of the installer. As I explained in the question, my company is trying to find a new installer framework that is less constricting in the order in which everything has to be done. If you can schedule and action more than once, some of those constraints could theoretically disappear.

Comment: This would be a good 2 hour beer conversation.  Don't get me wrong.. I love, and sometimes hate, Windows Installer.  But it's the best thing out there.  That said, it's a rigid declarative framework and it generally requires you to color within the lines.  When you really, really understand it, you learn ways to subvert it.  But generally it is best to not fight it as things will generally end poorly, often in ways you couldn't imagine because you don't know what you don't know.

Comment: FWIW, I describe the execute sequence table as the "tear the house down and built it back up pattern".  When you build a house things generally have to be done in a certain order.  First grading, utilities, foundation rough in, pouring concrete, framing, roofing, doors and windows, siding  and then so on.  For an install it's the same.  Create folders, copy files, apply registry, create service, start service, create shortcut and so on. During an uninstall you reverse the process.  During an upgrade you first reverse the process and then move it forward.

Comment: Just as you wouldn't want to go rip the roof off of a house after the carpet is in, you generally don't want to repeat a step during an installer.

Answer (score 3):

For custom actions, you're best bet is to design a table driven custom action that acts like the Windows Installer standard tables do. In that design, an immediate custom action is scheduled at the appropriate time relative to all the other actions. For example, `Before='RemoveFiles'` or `After='InstallFiles'` (or whatever.

The immediate custom action reads rows out of one or more custom tables that provide the data to the action. Multiple rows allow you to have the action run "more than once" by reading more data. If you need to modify machine state, the immediate custom action then schedules one or more deferred custom actions with the appropriate `CustomActionData`.  In this case, the deferred custom actions will be executed as may times as you schedule them.  You schedule a custom action using ::MsiDoAction() but I prefer to use WcaDoAction() provided by the WiX toolset's wcautil.lib.

This design is documented in the MSI SDK about deferred custom actions and the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) uses the pattern for all of it's custom actions.  It is very powerful and works extremely well when considering other scenarios such as repair, patching and uninstall.

Comment: Following some more research into this topic, there is one question I should ask you, Rob.

Do msi sequence tables **have** to include standard actions?

Comment: No. You won't get standard behavior (and might not be able to depend on some standard behavior) but a sequence can run arbitrary actions.